# Auto-fit table column widths based on content

Tags: tables, automation, columns, width

Is there any solution in LaTeX tables that implements similar functionality to MSWord's AutoFit?

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific about what AutoFit does?  Adjusts the column widths---with what goal?

Comment: MSWord is not clear about that. I would say the overall goal is to minimizes height of the table while maintaining its total width.

Comment: Ah, I see.  This sounds almost like a linear programming problem!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look at the [`tabulary`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabulary) package. Its description reads:

> The package defines a `tabular*`-like
>   tabulary environment, taking a ‘total
>   width’ argument as well as the column
>   specifications. It then defines column
>   types `L`, `C`, `R` and `J` for
>   variable width columns
>   (`\raggedright'`, `\centering`,
>   `\raggedleft`, and normally
>   justified). In contrast to
>   `tabularx`'s X columns, the width of
>   each column is weighted according to
>   the natural width of the widest cell
>   in the column.

In my example, I also use the [`ragged2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package to allow for hyphenation within the table cells.

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\usepackage{tabulary}

\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabulary}{0.8\textwidth}{LLL}
Definition and Validation of Dynamic Video Reframing based on & Definition and Validation of & Definition and Validation of Dynamic \\
Definition and Validation of Dynamic & Definition and Validation of & Definition and Validation of \\
\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Fixed a bug in an earlier version of this post that had a missing '\'.)

Comment: Note that `tabulary` doesn't have a fixed total width. The 'total width' argument acts as an upper limit on the width.