# A problem with table in landscape mode

Tags: tables, landscape

[I have a wide table that i wish to place in landscape mode to make it readable.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25371/80573) Additionally, i use `tabulary` to [autofit column width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16842/auto-fit-table-column-widths-based-on-content).

```
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[p]
        \caption{Candidate DACs\label{tab:dac}}
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|}
        \hline 
        \textbf{Manufacturer} & \textbf{Model} & \textbf{Resolution} & \textbf{Accuracy (typ./max.),} LSB & \textbf{Samples availible?}
        & \textbf{Price on Mouser}& \textbf{Broadband noise}, $\unit{nV}/\sqrt{\mathrm{Hz}}$ & \textbf{Pro} & \textbf{Contra} \\ 
        \hline 
        &  &  &  &  &  &  & ngmfkjig ojojo &  \\ 
        \hline 
        &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
        \hline 
        &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
        \hline 
        &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
        \hline 
        &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
        \hline 
        \end{tabulary} 

\end{table}

\end{landscape}
```

However, the width of the table stays as if the page was in portait mode. I tried to use `\textheight` as parameter to no avail.
[image]
I use LuaLatex. Please help me!

Comment: Perhaps try replacing `\textwidth` with `\textheight`

Comment: @Bernard this doesn't help, as I mentioned in the post

Comment: Could you post a full compilable code?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `\textwidth` use `\linewidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[p]
        \caption{Candidate DACs\label{tab:dac}}
    \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}% <---- changed
                                {|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Manufacturer} & \textbf{Model} & \textbf{Resolution} & \textbf{Accuracy (typ./max.),} LSB & \textbf{Samples availible?}
        & \textbf{Price on Mouser}& \textbf{Broadband noise}, $\mathrm{nV}/\sqrt{\mathrm{Hz}}$ & \textbf{Pro} & \textbf{Contra} \\
        \hline
        &  &  &  &  &  &  & ngmfkjig ojojo &  \\
        \hline
        &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
        \hline
        &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
        \hline
        &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
        \hline
        &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
        \hline
        \end{tabulary}
\end{table}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of nesting a `table` environment inside a `landscape` environment, and having to fiddle with the parameters, I suggest you load the `rotating` package and use its `sidewaystable` environment.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex    
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,tabulary,rotating}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more "open" look
\caption{Candidate DACs\label{tab:dac}}

    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{|L|l|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|}
    \hline 
    \textbf{Manufacturer} & \textbf{Model} & \textbf{Resolution} & \textbf{Accuracy (typ.\slash max.)}, LSB & \textbf{Samples availible?}
    & \textbf{Price on Mouser}& \textbf{Broadband noise}, 
    \si{\nano\volt}/$\sqrt{\si{\hertz}}$ 
    & \textbf{Pro} & \textbf{Contra} \\ 
    \hline 
    &  &  &  &  &  &  & ngmfkjig ojojo &  \\ 
    \hline 
    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline 
    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline 
    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline 
    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline 
    \end{tabulary} 

\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know that this possible, I chose the landscape approach because the page will be properly dsiplayed in pdf then .see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25369/how-to-rotate-a-table?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment466033_25371

Comment: @AndreyPro - I truly do not understand the relevance of that quote you've located, either for the original posting or for your new posting. (Aside: I find that quote to be both obnoxious and ill-informed.) Whether one uses the composite `landscape`/`table` approach or the one-step `sidewaystable` approach, the output is a table that's turned 90 degrees in both cases. The main difference between the two approaches, then, is not in their output but in the complexity of the inputs.

Comment: the difference is how it displayed on screen whe you view the pdf: `sidewaystable` rotates the table making the content vertical, and inconvenient to view. landscape mode rotates the page itself, so the content is displayed horizontally

Comment: @AndreyPro - The way a pdf viewer shows pages onscreen depends both on the particular pdf viewer (and its default settings) and on whether the defaults were modified. It's straightforward to program Adobe Acrobat to display landscape-oriented pages onscreen in, you guessed, landscape orientation.